# Unable to install AngularJs2

Tags: angular

It had been a while since I used npm or node. I tried to install angularjs2, to learn it, and when I tried to install I got the following error. I also tried to update npm or instal nodejs again, clean cache (force clean) no go. any fixes for this issue?

> maddyspc:Documents username$ sudo npm install -g angular-cli npm ERR!
>   Darwin 15.2.0 npm ERR! argv "node"
>   "/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli" npm
>   ERR! node v0.9.6 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
>
> npm ERR! Unknown encoding: buffer npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you need help,
>   you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> buffer.js:405
>         throw new Error('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
>               ^ Error: Unknown encoding: buffer
>       at Buffer.write (buffer.js:405:13)
>       at new Buffer (buffer.js:261:26)
>       at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:134:13)
>       at WriteStreamAtomic._write (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic/index.js:64:37)
>       at doWrite (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:319:64)
>       at writeOrBuffer (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:308:5)
>       at WriteStreamAtomic.Writable.write (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:246:11)
>       at WriteStreamAtomic.Writable.end (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:456:51)
>       at writeLogFile (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:8)
>       at exit (/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.6/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:82:5)

Comment: I tried to remove node, all of nodemodules and tried installing again no go

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
I had node version 0.9 activated and due to which even the latest version of node when installed using the packager node-v4.6.0.pkg on my MAC OSX was not activating the latest version. This happens if you have HomeBrew. Even when I did a clean uninstall and install of node the issue of updating to the latest node version was not happening.
So I tried the following steps and this fixed this issue

`nvm -v
nvm ls
nvm uninstall 0.9.6
nvm install 6.7.0
sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest`

Angular2 installed. I tested by creating the app and running 'ng serve' and it worked!